# Onclick for HTML5 Audio with Phonegap and Xcode

Tags: xcode, html, audio, cordova

I am trying to build an HTML5 soundboard with Phonegap; I want users to tap on an image and hear a short audio clip. I have it working in the browser (Chrome and Safari), but it's not working in Xcode.

Here is a link to a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/lamike/qHGqh/

Screencast:

http://screencast.com/t/TbXCilji

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that any external URLs in your app are listed in the WhiteList? I tried a quick cut and paste project with the code from the JSFiddle and I was able to click Obama and hear the beginning of the podcast.

See the PhoneGap for iOS FAQ: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/41631150/PhoneGap%20for%20iOS%20FAQ

**Q. Links to and imported files from external hosts don't load?**

**A.** The latest code has the new white-list feature. If you are referencing external hosts, you will have to add the host in PhoneGap.plist under the "ExternalHosts" key. Wildcards are ok. So if you are connecting to "http://phonegap.com", you have to add "phonegap.com" to the list (or use the wildcard "*.phonegap.com" which will match subdomains as well).

Comment: That's weird that it's not working for me in Xcode, I have another page in my app that has links to other podcasts, so I already have the wildcard "*" in the p.list... Should I put two wildcards in there? http://i41.tinypic.com/2cpb72a.png

Comment: * should certainly cover it. What exactly happens / doesn't happen for you? Which version of PhoneGap, etc

Comment: I think I'm on phongeap 3.0.. here is a screencast I made walking through the problem http://screencast.com/t/TbXCilji

Comment: I am not sure why the other sounds don't fire, but the first one does... and the local one you have referenced as "red ban" even though the actual folder is called "Redban". html paths are case sensitive.

Comment: Hmm I changed the reference to Redban, but still no luck. I don't get what you are trying to say with the last comment; but any other suggestions would be great, thanks!